# jquery mobile anchor link is not working

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, hyperlink

I'm trying to put an anchor link in my web page but when I click **go to top** link nothing happen. I'm using jquery mobile.

**Code:**

```
<div data-role="content">
      <a id="home_top">top</a>
      <ul id="home_index_ul" data-role="listview">
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
           ...
      </ul>
      <a href="#home_top">go to top</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `.silentScroll()` in JQM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.slientScroll](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/)

```
<a href="#" onclick="$.mobile.silentScroll(0)" data-role="button">go to Top</a>
```